# find all possible combinations of elements of an array. NOT PRODUCT

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, combinations, computational-geometry

Ive looked into this question and people keep advising to use `np.meshgrid()` to find all possible combinations of an array. but the problem is `np.meshgrid()` does not produce combinations it produces products (similar to itertools.product())

in a combination, elements are non-repeating and unordered

```
arr = np.arange(5)
r = 3
```

These are what combinations look like

```
np.array(
    list(itertools.combinations(arr, r))
)

>>>   [[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 4],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [0, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4]]
```

following are not combinations

```
np.array(
    list(itertools.product(arr, arr, arr))
)

>>>   [[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       ....,
       [4, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 3],
       [4, 3, 4],
       [4, 4, 0],
       [4, 4, 1],
       [4, 4, 2],
       [4, 4, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

```
np.array(
    np.meshgrid(arr, arr, arr)
).transpose([2, 1, 3, 0]).reshape(-1, r)

>>>   [[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 4],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2],
       ....,
       [4, 3, 2],
       [4, 3, 3],
       [4, 3, 4],
       [4, 4, 0],
       [4, 4, 1],
       [4, 4, 2],
       [4, 4, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

for `r = 2` i've found a neat way to find combinations

```
np.array(
    np.triu_indices(len(arr), 1)
).T

>>>   [[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4]]
```

but im having a hard time finding any vectorized methods for `r > 2`

> NOTE:
> even if my array is not `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` i could use the above answers as indices.

if it helps to imagine,

for `r = 2` the required answer is indices of top-right triangle of a square matrix of size `len(arr)`, ignoring the diagonal.

for `r = 3` the required answer is indices of top-right-upper tetrahedron (middle one in the image) of a 3d array of size (you guessed it) `len(arr)`, ignoring the 3d equivalent of diagonal.

[image]

Comment: "permutations"? `from itertools import permutations` `list(permutations(arr, 3))` Maybe.

Comment: permutations are different than combinations, and im looking for a vectoriszed implementation soo `itertools` is a no no.

Comment: @Hammad Is there a reason you need to vectorize it?

Comment: @Ehsan i have a large dataset, so i want to avoid looping and generators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to your idea for 3-D:

```
n = 5
r = 3
a = np.argwhere(np.triu(np.ones((n,)*r),1))
a[a[:,0]<a[:,1]]
```

output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [0 1 4]
 [0 2 3]
 [0 2 4]
 [0 3 4]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 4]
 [1 3 4]
 [2 3 4]]
```

for 4-D (and so on) you can expand like this (Not sure of the performance):

```
n = 5
r = 4
a = np.argwhere(np.triu(np.ones((n,)*r),1))
a[(a[:,0]<a[:,1]) & (a[:,1]<a[:,2])]
```

output:

```
[[0 1 2 3]
 [0 1 2 4]
 [0 1 3 4]
 [0 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4]]
```

Itertools seems to be faster if that is what you are aiming at:

```
def m1(n):
  r = 3
  a = np.argwhere(np.triu(np.ones((n,)*r),1))
  return a[a[:,0]<a[:,1]]

def m2(n):
  r = 3
  return combinations(np.arange(n),r)

in_ = [5,10,100,200]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, the `itertools` implementation is only faster because youre only returning the generator, which would later be needed to convert into an array and take significant amount of time

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code:

```
def triu_indices(n, k=0, m=None):
    return nonzero(~tri(n, m, k=k-1, dtype=bool))

def tri(N, M=None, k=0, dtype=float):
    m = greater_equal.outer(arange(N, dtype=_min_int(0, N)),
                        arange(-k, M-k, dtype=_min_int(-k, M - k)))
```

So for a square:

```
In [75]: np.greater_equal.outer(np.arange(5),np.arange(5))                                           
Out[75]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
In [76]: np.argwhere(~np.greater_equal.outer(np.arange(5),np.arange(5)))                             
Out[76]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

Or using `ix_` to create broadcastable ranges:

```
In [77]: I,J = np.ix_(np.arange(5),np.arange(5))                                                     
In [78]: I,J                                                                                         
Out[78]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4]]),
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]))
In [79]: I>=J                                                                                        
Out[79]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
In [80]: I<J                                                                                         
Out[80]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Generalizing this to 3d:

```
In [90]: I,J,K = np.ix_(np.arange(5),np.arange(5),np.arange(5))                                      
In [91]: np.argwhere((I<J) & (J<K))                                                                  
Out[91]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 4],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4],
       [0, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

This makes a (5,5,5) array, and then finds the True.  So it's not surprising that its timeing isn't as good as `itertools`:

```
In [92]: %%timeit 
    ...: I,J,K = np.ix_(np.arange(5),np.arange(5),np.arange(5))   
    ...: np.argwhere((I<J) & (J<K))                                                                                             
60.4 µs ± 97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [99]: timeit np.array(list(itertools.combinations(np.arange(5), 3)))                              
20.9 µs ± 1.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

just running some bench marks for the answers

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import perfplot
```

`itertools` implementation

```
def func0(n, r):
    
    r = np.array(
        list(itertools.combinations(range(n), r))
    )
    
    return r
```

@hpaulj 's implementation

```
def func1(n, r):
    
    prod = np.argwhere(np.ones(r*[n], dtype= bool))
    mask = True
    
    for i in range(r-1): mask = mask & (prod[:, i] < prod[:, i+1])
        
    return prod[mask]
```

@Ehsan 's implementation

```
def func2(n, r):
    
    rngs = (np.arange(n), )*r
    indx = np.ix_(*rngs)
    mask = True
    
    for i in range(r-1): mask = mask & (indx[i] < indx[i+1])
        
    return np.argwhere(mask)
```

performance w.r.t `n`

```
bench_n = perfplot.bench(
    n_range= range(4, 50),
    setup  = lambda n: n,
    kernels= [
        lambda n: func0(n, 4),
        lambda n: func1(n, 4),
        lambda n: func2(n, 4)
    ],
    labels = ['func0', 'func1', 'func2']
)

bench_n.show()
```

[image]

performance w.r.t `r`

```
bench_r = perfplot.bench(
    n_range= range(2, 8),
    setup  = lambda r: r,
    kernels= [
        lambda r: func0(10, r),
        lambda r: func1(10, r),
        lambda r: func2(10, r)
    ],
    labels = ['func0', 'func1', 'func2']
)

bench_r.show()
```

[image]